# Encontrar las posiciones en las cuales los elementos ubicados en estas tengan la menor distancia entre ellos

Tags: java

Mi pregunta es, como puedo buscar dentro del arreglo las posiciones en las cuales los elementos ubicados en estas tengan la menor distancia entre ellos, un ejemplo de esto seria que teniendo el siguiente arreglo:

```
arr = {5, 50, 3, 42, 18, 16, 8, 30, 44}
```

mis Dmin serian la diferencia entre los numeros con menor distancia entre si, en este caso,

```
Dmin1 = 5-3 = 2; 

Dmin2 = 18-16 = 2;

Dmin3 44-42 = 2;
```

Sin que se repita el indice del número en el arreglo. Tengo hecho este código pero tengo dificultad de encontrar lo que busco.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        int [] arr= {5, 50, 3, 42, 18, 16, 8, 30, 44};      // Array
        menorD l = new menorD();        

        menorD.MinD(arr);   

      }

}

public class  menorD {

    static int arr_zise;


    public static void minD (int [] arr) {

        arr_zise = arr.length;
        int i, j;
        int minD=0;

        for(i=0;i<arr_zise; i++) {

            for(j=0;j<arr_zise; j++) {

                if(arr[i]!=arr[j]) {
                    minD=arr[i]-arr[j];

                System.out.print(" i="+ arr[i]+ " j="+ arr[j]+ " minD es: "+Math.abs(min));
                    System.out.println();

                }


            }

        }


    }


}
```

Comment: ¿qué lenguaje estas usando?, pues pusiste tres distintos

Comment: Java, agregue los otros por ser lenguajes con sistaxis muy similares.